# Is it possible to include multiple modes in CodeMirror 2?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Is it possible to include two or more modes in the CodeMirror 2 instance?

e.g.

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
    value: "Hello World",
    mode: "css", "html", "javascript"
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `htmlmixed` mode. It depends on `xml`, `javascript` and `css` modes.

Comment: It does not highlight the other codes if we use htmlmixed. For example in htmlmixed mode it does not highlight the jquery code but it does for html